# Execute command using exec and pass the process id to another command

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, process, exec

I would you to execute a command in Linux and get the process id of the launched process and pass it to another command.

I tried the `$!` variable in bash, it works if the process launched directly like this:

```
ls &
echo $!
```

But if I use exec like this:

```
exec ls &
echo $!
```

the `$!` variable would be blank.

I have to use exec. Any clue how to get this right?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have to use the shell's `exec` feature, or can you use it from a program?

Comment: Your `exec` example doesn't run `ls` in the background as a child of the current shell. It attempts to replace the current shell with an executable named "ls &".

Comment: Also, why do you need `exec`? The purpose of using `exec` is that it doesn't return. Do you just want to avoid the extra subshell which runs the command? Try `exec ls &`, in which the subshell spawned by `&` is replaced by `ls`.

Comment: @chepner `exec ls &` does, in fact, execute `ls` in the background.  I would guess the `&` takes precedence (i.e., the `exec` is redundant).

Comment: @goldilocks Yeah, I'm not sure what situation I'm thinking of; something like `( do-something; do-something-else & ) &`, perhaps. Your answer is spot on.

Comment: Why do you think you have to use `exec`?  You use `exec` to replace the current process with the program in the argument list to `exec`.  But the `ls &` process basically does that anyway, so it is not clear what benefit you get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the $! variable would be blank.

Did you even try this?

```
> exec ls & echo "pid = $!"
[1] 29443
pid = 29443
```

Evidently it is not as blank as you theorized it would be.  The process does not have to complete; the pid is available immediately.